# apache Ivy pulling artifact from AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: amazon-web-services, ivy, aws-codeartifact

I am working on an ant project, trying to download the artifact from AWS CodeArtifact using apache ivy. My ivysettings.xml is

```
<ivysettings>
    <properties file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings-file.properties"/>
    <settings defaultResolver="thechain"/>
    <credentials
        host="i****.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
        username="aws"
        passwd="${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="thechain">
            <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" 
                root="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" />
            <ibiblio name="codeartifact" m2compatible="true" 
                root="https://i****.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/maven/****-repo/" checkconsistency="false"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

It failed

```
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== codeartifact: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    https://i***.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/maven/*-3.0.1-6.pom
[ivy:retrieve]    -- artifact com.viscount#alarmserver;3.0.1-6!alarmserver.jar:
[ivy:retrieve]    https://i***.d.codeartifact.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/maven/*-3.0.1-6.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: com.*#*;3.0.1-6: not found
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

In the credential, I skipped the realm and set the host name using the host part of the url.  I wonder if that is correct? There is no documentation on the AWS Codeartifact about setting the host and the realm.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the dependency can't be found, not that there are any permission issues.  Are you sure you have the version information for `alarmserver.jar` correct?

Comment: It turned out I need to provide the realm. When I ran the build from netbeans, it prompted me for login and password and the pop up windows showed the realm. After I provided the realm, ivy can fetch the jar file from AWS codeartifacts. Thanks!